# Cannot start httpd on CentOS

Tags: apache, centos

I cannot restart apache on CentOS. The results are below. I cannot locate a meaningful error to fix the issue.

Running `service httpd start`

Results in

> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Then running `systemctl status httpd.service`

Results in

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-06-11 08:29:11 EDT; 15min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 640 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 638 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
 Main PID: 638 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

Jun 11 08:29:11 server systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 11 08:29:11 server systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jun 11 08:29:11 server kill[640]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jun 11 08:29:11 server systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 11 08:29:11 server systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 11 08:29:11 server systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jun 11 08:29:11 server systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

And `journalctl -xe`

Results in

```
Jun 11 08:45:10 server systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Jun 11 08:45:10 server systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jun 11 08:45:10 server kill[691]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jun 11 08:45:10 server systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 11 08:45:10 server systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jun 11 08:45:10 server systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jun 11 08:45:10 server systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

And from  `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log`

```
[Sun Jun 11 08:49:33.214825 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 761] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Jun 11 08:49:33.237392 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 761] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jun 11 08:49:33.238036 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 761] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
PHP Fatal error:  PHP Startup: apc_shm_create: shmget(0, 67108864, 914) failed: Invalid argument. It is possible that the chosen SHM segment size is higher than the operation system allows. Linux has usually a default limit of 32MB per segment. in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  PHP Startup: apc_shm_attach: shmat failed: in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Hm, anything in your http servers error log file?

Comment: Have a try starting the server process directly from the command line. So `/usr/sbin/httpd`.

Comment: @arkascha answer updated

Comment: Ok, at least some hint onto what the issue is, though not really as clear as hoped for. Those are packages installed form the official repositories?

Comment: Try removing the APC cache for a try. Does the daemon startup correctly then?

Comment: Ah ha! Yes, disabling APC in PHP7 lets it start up

Comment: It's likely that APC is trying to allocate more shared memory than the kernel allows. Is the value in /etc/php.d/ext-apc.ini for `apc.shm_size` greater than `sysctl kernel.shmmax`?

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the case `sysctl kernel.shmmax` is 32M and `apc.shm_size` is 64M - now the question is which should I change?

Comment: Depends in multiple factors, keep it conservative at first, so 32M.

Comment: OK thanks for your help!